# Cannot get mp4 video to play in Opera (or Edge)

Tags: video, microsoft-edge, opera

I am trying to embed a video in a web page, displayed in Opera (80.0.4170.72).

I have never used the  tag before, so as a start copied the example straight out of W3Schools:

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/cinefilms/7.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Doesn't work. The page loads, the player appears, sits there for a second or two with a rotating wait indicator, then just sits there. MS Edge does the same.

If I replace the  tag with an `<a>` tag (`<a href="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/cinefilms/7.mp4">video</a>`), then on clicking it the browser displays the video player itself (no help from me), but again it behaves as before, doesn't play.

If I right click on the hyperlink from the `<a>` tag and select 'save linked content as' I can download the file and play it OK in VLC, so it is definitely there and a good file (about 50MB).

Don't understand what is going on, feel I must have missed something obvious. (If I try it in IE, it says 'your browser does not support the video tag', but with the `<a>` tag it will download and play it in VLC).

Update: doesn't work in Chrome, either.

Comment: Is there any error in console in F12 dev tools? Could you please try to load the W3Schools example video https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4 to see if it can load well? If it can load well, I think there might be some issues with your video source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp4 is the container for your video.  But what is the codec?  (You can check it by entering the video URL at https://ffprobe.a.video).

I'm betting it is encoded as H.265 HVEC - which is not supported in Opera/edge (actually only in Safari - https://caniuse.com/?search=h265).

To get the mp4 to playback in all browsers, you'll want to transcode it to h264 (98.1% support on the web) https://caniuse.com/?search=h264

Comment: Dead right. It was the video file. It was MP4(DivX compatible), changed conversion to MP4(AVC), I think it said h264 somewhere. It was OK then. I thought it was AVI that was just a wrapper for different formats.

Comment: Correction, the MP4 format that worked was 'avc/h264'.